# Usb serial connection of FT232BL

Tags: android, usb-drive, ftdi

I am working on an Android project. I want to make an Android app and load to an Android tablet. My goal is control the peripheral device over the Android app installed Android device. Therefore, I researched on the Internet to send/receive data over USB, and I saw the FTDI chip.

I have an FT232BL. I loaded the D2XXsample and driver and also read and processed TN_134_FTDI_Android_D2XX_Driver.pdf and TN_147_Java_D2xx_for_Android.pdf. But I don't achieve to connect the Android tablet and peripheral device. How can I fix this?

Comment: does the ftdi works when connecting to pc?

Comment: Yes I will see the FTDI chip on pc. And it work good on our peripheral device. The FT232BL is on a working system.